AWS SES email to myself lags over 20 minutes
I am trying to send emails to myself using Amazon Simple Email Service within a Lambda Function
import pandas as pd 
import boto3 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4]})
html_table = df.to_html(index=False)
ses_client = boto3.client('ses')
sender_email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
recipient_email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
subject = 'Hello World'
body_html = f"""
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            {html_table}
          </body>
        </html>
    """
    response = ses_client.send_email(
        Source=sender_email,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [recipient_email],
        },
        Message={
            'Subject': {
                'Data': subject,
            },
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Data': body_html,
                },
            },
        }
    )
return response

I have a process that sends this email from 9am-5pm every hour to myself. The lambda function always "succeeds" very quickly, but I've noticed that in the mornings, the email gets delivered immediately, while later in the afternoon, there's between a 20min-60min lag from when I send it until when I receive it.
I inspected the headers with https://www.dmarctester.com/ and it says the DMARC Result is "FAIL" (also the SPF/DKIM fail), because amazonses.com != gmail.com . What's the best way to get around this issue? Note: I don't have a DNS name to use, and am using the Sandbox because I dont have the DNS. Is AWS SES just meant for corporations / is there another alternative way to send email to myself (and maybe a few other people later)? I've tried using SNS Topics too but they don't support HTML formatting, which I need.

You can get a domain name for less than $10 a year. That is certainly not "just for corporations".

Thanks, realized it's pretty simple to get from Route53 and integrates nicely with SES.
